# Converting a JSON Link into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction

Please look at the following explanation for the problem.
I have a JSON Data Source: https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/x8jf-txib/rows.json and I want to convert this Data into a Pandas Data frame.

If you look at the JSON Dataset, it consists of MetaData and then the Actual Data. I would like to have a way in which I can store Metadata in a different file while the Dataset in a different file in my local System.

I have developed this method and I am not able to get it completely work for me:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
​
# Get the dataset
url = "https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/x8jf-txib/rows.json"
response = urlopen(url)
​
# Convert bytes to string type and string type to dict
string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)
```

The above Step converts the JSON File in a Dictionary and when I try to convert it into Pandas Dataframe by using this:

```
pd.DataFrame([json_obj.items()])
```

I get the output as this:

[image]

Please help me for this! I appreciate it.

Comment: try `pd.DataFrame(json_obj['data'])`

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `json.loads` gives you back a map/object if the JSON string was parsed properly. I think what you want to construct the `DataFrame` is the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_obj['data'])
```

Here's a working script:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

# Get the dataset
url = "https://data.cdc.gov/api/views/x8jf-txib/rows.json"
response = urlopen(url)

# Convert bytes to string type and string type to dict
string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_obj['data'])
print(df.head())
```

You should get output that looks something like:

```
                   0                                     1   2   ...                            38    39    40
0  row-ss5i~ibqh-im6e  00000000-0000-0000-E6C3-33C094361E41   0  ...                          None  None  None
1  row-7jrs-n8wf_crzs  00000000-0000-0000-22EC-13B75E5E7127   0  ...                          None  None  None
2  row-ddqq-yzd7.yyhz  00000000-0000-0000-319D-A1D4FB17A377   0  ...                          None  None  None
3  row-kzem-t4xs.n4ss  00000000-0000-0000-6ED5-CF3857CC1862   0  ...                          None  None  None
4  row-9ws9-2nrx~xqqg  00000000-0000-0000-3403-E46EFF15AE5B   0  ...  POINT (-89.148632 40.124144)  1721    34
```

Comment: Hello Sir,
Thank you for your Response.
Actually after posting this Question, I was able to seperate my Meta Data from my Actual Data and then convert it to a Data Frame.
 What I would love to know is that if you dont want to save the JSON file on your Local machine and directly access it from the Website and convert it in a data frame for analysis, how can we achieve the same.

Comment: You have to have the data stored locally somewhere to read it. The way this code works now is that the data is saved into memory in the python process.

Comment: Is there a way to read directly the data from the website rather than saving in the local system